# Image texture isn't colourful

Tags: texturing, color

I added a simple yellow image texture as material, but when I apply it to an object, it becomes less strong, it is not colourful. Even if I want to render it in Evee or Cycles, it also not as colourful as the original picture. How can I correct the colour to make it the same as on the added picture?

Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Make sure that in the Render panel > Color Management > View Transform > you are in Standard mode. Also if you want the pure color without any light or shadow affecting it use an Emission shader, not the Principled BSDF or the Diffuse shader. If it still doesn't work please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/